# On holomorphic branched coverings of a domain in the plane to the unit disk

Tags: cv.complex-variables

This question is partly motivated by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95570/does-constant-modulus-on-boundary-of-annulus-imply-constant-function/95581#95581) on math.stackexchange.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded $n$-connected domain in the plane, bounded by $n$ pairwise disjoint Jordan curves.

It was proved by Ahlfors that by solving an extremal problem (related to so-called *analytic capacity*), one can obtain a function $f$ holomorphic in $\Omega$ with the following properties :

1. $f$ is an $n$-to-$1$ branched covering of $\Omega$ onto the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$,
2. $f$ extends continuously to the boundary of $\Omega$, and maps each boundary curve homeomorphically onto the unit circle.

See e.g. Krantz's *Geometric function theory: explorations in complex analysis*, theorem 4.5.9.

My question is :

**Is there another (perhaps more intuitive) way to see that such a function necessarily exists?**

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but heuristically, this should hold true by consider branched covers over the disk with appropriate branching data. One may obtain an n-punctured sphere as a branched cover over a disk with n branched points. The dimension of Teichmuller space of an n-punctured sphere is 2n-3, which is the same as the dimension of the space of n points in a disk, modulo the mobius group. So this gives a map between Teichmuller spaces, which one would like to prove is onto. I'm not sure how to give an elementary proof of this though. 

Comment: I think you can do this by multiplying together functions coming from the Riemann mapping, one for each Jordan curve, then multiply by a term of the form $\exp(u(z)+iv(z))$ where $u$ is harmonic and chosen to make the Jordan curves map to the unit circle and $v$ is chosen to make $u+iv$ analytic. It could be that $v$ is multiple-valued (so, only defined on the covering surface) but, by combining the Riemann map terms with Mobius transformations on the unit disc, you can make sure that $v$ is singly valued. That's a rough sketch I have in my head anyway.

Comment: Or, which amounts to the same thing, choose n points $P=\lbrace z_1,\ldots,z_n\rbrace$ in the domain and define a harmonic function on the domain minus P by $f(z)=\log\vert z-z_1\vert+\cdots+\log\vert z-z_n\vert+u(z)$ where $u$ is harmonic and chosen such that $f=0$ on the boundary. You can extend $f$ to a (multiple-valued) harmonic function $g(z)=f(z)+iv(z)$. Choosing $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ carefully, you can make this a singly valued function, and the mapping is given by $h(z)=\exp(g(z)$.

Comment: @Geoge : I thought about doing this, but it's not clear to me how you can choose $z_1, \dots, z_n$ so that the resulting function will be single valued... Note that this requirement puts constraints on $z_1, \dots, z_n$, so there are choices of the $z_j$'s that won't work.

Comment: @Agol : Your heuristic remark about the corresponding Teichmuller spaces is very interesting, thank you.


Comment: @Agol: I certainly believe this would work, I think though that the Teichmuller spaces are not of the same dimension.  The Teichmuller space of a sphere minus n disks has dimension 3n-6.  An euler characteristic argument shows that the map to the disk is branched over 2n-2 points, so that Teichmuller space has dimension 4n-7.  So the map will be surjective with a large dimensional fiber.

Comment: @unknown(google): you're right, I don't know where I got 2g-3 from! One can obtain the n-punctured disk branched over the n-disk with n branch points, e.g. a generic polynomial of degree n sends the complement of the n roots to the complement of zero (in the Riemann sphere) has n-1 branched points of degree 2 (at the roots of the derivative) and one branched point of degree n at infinity. But I guess given the correct dimension computation, this will not be onto (except possibly for n=3). One could also consider maps of higher degree. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now know a lot more about this question than I did when I asked it, so for the sake of completness let me add :

By applying the Riemann mapping theorem $n$ times, we can assume that $\Omega$ is bounded by *analytic* Jordan curves. In this case, we have the following theorem due to Bieberbach, which says that there are many proper holomorphic maps onto the unit disk.

**Theorem**
Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ bounded by disjoint analytic Jordan curves $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$, and let $p \in X$. For each $j$, fix a point $\alpha_j \in E_j$. Then there is a unique proper holomorphic map $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(\alpha_j)=1$ for all $j$ and $f(p)$=0.

For more information about proper holomorphic mappings, see the preprint [there](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5042).